# Communicating with USB port with C# and figure out protocol

Tags: c#, usb, communication

Does anyone know of any c# code example of listening to and logging the communication to and from a USB device?

My problem is as follows:
I have a Weather Station (265 NE) which I connect to the computer via USB. The provided application for transfering data from the weather station i quite crappy. Now I'd like to write an application that handles the communication for me.
Therefor I need some code example showing how to figure out how the weather station and the computer communicates and then reproduce the communication from my own piece of code.

I've googled a lot to find an answer to this but with no luck.

Cheers

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this tutorial might be a good start;

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/